# Android - Do I have to have WeakRererence for inner asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

LEts say I have an private class AsyncTask in an Activity.
This activity executes this Asynctask and in doInBackground() it loads data from the web.
in onPostExecute(), it changes/updates the UI component of the Activity.

Here are my questions.
1. Is it always a good habit to separate Activity and Asynctask? 
I am asking this because I tend to use AsyncTask as an inner class so that I can easily access Activity's UI components from onPostExecute() so that I can easily update them. However, I somehow feel this is not a good practice. So if it is not, when do I have to separate them?

1. When do I have to keep weakReference inside AsyncTask? I know this is used for prevending memory leak upon config change. Do I have to keep it all the time? If I have an inner AsyncTask, do I have to have a weakREference there too?
2. If I have a separate AsncTask, which is better to keep as a weakreference? Context? or Activity? Or does it matter?
3. Let's say I have a separate AsnycTask. I do some heavy stuff in the doInBackground(). After that I want to update a lot of UI components in the activity that executed this AsycTask. What is an efficient way to perform this update? If I want to update the UI components with the results I got in the doInBackground(), where should I perform the update, in Activity or onPostExecute()?

Thanks!